# Setting active state on a Nav item depending on the Route using ReactBootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, opalrb, hyperstack

What is the best way of ensuring the correct Nav Item is selected using React Bootstrap and Hyperstack Router?

I know I can the `Link` method, but I want to use the specific Bootstrap `Nav` item instead.

Is there a good example of this anyone can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React router actually handles this automatically!
I have used this in one of my apps, maybe it can help for inspiration:

```rb
class BS < Hyperstack::Component::NativeLibrary
  # subclasses of Hyperstack::Component::NativeLibrary
  # are wrappers around JS component libraries.
  # once imported BS acts like an ordinary ruby module

  imports 'ReactBootstrap'
end
```

```rb
class App < HyperComponent
  include Hyperstack::Router
  include Hyperstack::Router::Helpers

  ROUTES = {
    '/' => ['Home', Home],
    '/overview' => ['Overview', Overview]
  }

  render do
    DIV {
      H1 { "Hello there from Hyperstack!" }
      BS::Nav(variant: 'pills') {
        ROUTES.each do |k, v|
          BS::Nav.Item() {
            NavLink(k, class: 'nav-link', exact: true) { v[0] }
          }
        end
      }
      ROUTES.each do |k, v|
        Route(k, mounts: v[1], exact: true)
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent answer! One thing, you can avoid the first step by importing the whole library in your Webpack pack `import * as BS from 'react-bootstrap'; global.BS = BS;` or even better, import one component at a time so you keep your JS size down.